# Dynamic render function in Vue instance based on authentication check

Tags: vue.js, authentication, asynchronous, async-await, axios

I'm adding JWT authentication to my Vue app and I have my Login.vue and App.vue seperated which means that I don't want to render the App.vue when the user is not logged in.

```js
new Vue({
    router,
    render: function (app) {
        if (this.$auth.check()) {
            return app(App);
        } else {
            return app(Login);
        }
    }
}).$mount('#app')
```

This works but since

```js
this.$auth.check()
```

Takes a second to load you see the Login app being rendered for a second and then it switches to the App. How can I fix this? I think I should use await but I can't get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix this? I think I should use await but I can't get it to work properly.

It depends on what is `this.$auth.check()` return. If it returns a promise, the answer is yes you should use `await`.

But unfortunately `render` function must be synchronous. <del>What you can do is use one more wrapper component</del>.

```js
new Vue({
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement({
      data: () => ({
        component: null
      }),
      async created() {
        this.component = await checkAuth() ? App : Login
      },
      render(createElement) {
        return createElement(this.component)
      }
    })
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pr4v6u3s/)

Note:

- I would prefer to create a wrapper component as single-file component.
- It seems you are using `vue-router` you might consider to use [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) instead.

**Update**

As you may be already notice you have no need a wrapper component at all.

```
new Vue({
  data: () => ({
    component: null
  }),
  async created() {
    this.component = await checkAuth() ? App : Login
  },
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement(this.component)
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```